# Multiple Vlans per NIC on Windows 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vlan

How do I have multiple vlans (tagged) go over one NIC in server 2008 R2?  I know it's possible in *nix and I know how to do that on the network side.  But it doesn't help if the server 2008 R2 can't understand that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What type of NIC do you have?  I know that Both Intel, and Broadcom provide a configuration utility.  All you do is install it, run it and follow the wizards to set up virtual interfaces for each VLAN you want to communicate on.

Comment: +1 The only way to do it is through the NIC's drivers/configuration utilities. Windows does not have this functionality natively.

Comment: Realtek does as well.

Comment: Much sadness and woe!  We are using HP specific configuration utilities and we haven't had and positive luck getting that to work at all so I was hoping there was a way to bypass that.  Thank you.